# How to optimize cosmoDB with partitioning and reduce cost eventually

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have a CosmoDb Database with 3 collections(concept like for each country, 1 collection) and each collection got 50 plus records. Now i want to optimze the collection , inorder to reduce the cost !

What is the best way to optimize the collections ?

Does partitioning helps to reduce the cost ?

Edited More Details: There are three countries say, US, Mexico,UK . I have 3 collections for each countries. USCollection , MexicoCollection, UKCollection. Each collection contains multiple records. Country ID is used as uniquekey in this records.  I have a write operation and a read operation.

NB : I already tried options to migrate CosmoDB Database to Azure storage table , since data structure of the document is nested and complicated , i came to a conclusion that it wouldn't be a nice idea.

Comment: This is a really broad question, and difficult to answer without seeing anything specific (you've just mentioned 3 collections, but with no detail).And cost isn't just about # of collections; it's also about the RU capacity you'll need for your particular use cases. Unfortunately there is no single "right" answer for such a question, given how generic it is.

Comment: There are three countries say, US, Mexico,UK . I have 3 collections for each countries. USCollection , MexicoCollection, UKCollection. Each collection contains multiple records. Country ID is used as uniquekey in this records. I have a write operation and a read operation. CountryCollection Name can give as partition key ?

Answer (score 1):

I would use 1 collection with a partition key for each country, instead of a collection per country. You pay per collection for the amount of RU/s reserved. Partition keys do not affect the cost, but will affect if you need to do cross partition queries which cost more RUs.

If you needed to keep separate collections for some reason, then you could potentially take advantage of Database level pricing, but that might not save you any money.

Best advice to save money is to make sure your indexes are set up properly so your write operations are fast/cheap, and your reads don't need to do scans.

-- Edited to mention the affect that cross partition queries have on RUs.

Comment: Without knowing the OP's query patterns, it's pretty difficult to predict the best partition key. Also, again regarding queries, partition keys *do* affect cost, since cross-partition queries can be far more expensive than single-partition queries.

Comment: Agreed. It is hard with the info provided, but OP still mentioned different collections, which is probably unnecessary. # of partition keys don't affect your cost directly, but your partition design will affect if you need cross-partition queries or multiple queries with client side joins, which will consume more RUs which *might* cause you to need to scale up, but it doesn't not directly cost more money to do such queries. It's important to distinguish because x-partition queries running at night or a second region might be fine and not require a scaling operation. YMMV. Edited answer.

Comment: More details on my problem :                                                                                  3 collections , UK008, Mexico008,UK008. Under UK008 there are plenty of records with unique id say, ProvinceID.   I have a single read query and single write query. Now can you tell me how i can reduce cost by making it single collection, and under it multiple records with partition key

Comment: You should update your original question with those details so others can find them and I can update my answer then. Could you share an example of what your query does and a sample scheme object?